# Java : How can I clear and sorting all contents in .txt file?

Tags: java, sorting

1. How can i sort all of my string content in .txt file based on alphabetical? For example :
   here's what inside the txt file :

   1. Jhon
   2. Anna
   3. Alice

   After sorting :

   1. Alice
   2. Anna
   3. Jhon
2. How would i clear all of the contents and leave only the empty txt file?

Comment: Show us that you have tried. We can help you to do your homework, but we cannot do it for u.

Comment: Are those numbers with the names part of the file?

Comment: no,the numbers are not the part of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        File file = new File("input.txt")
        List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset());
        Collections.sort(allLines);

        //For deleting
        file.delete();
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: ,Do you remember your yesterday method and function ? I need to sort them from the same "output.txt" , and how should i do if i want to make your code above become an function like the read method one ? I just tried the sorting and it didn't work

Comment: The sorting should work did you display the sorted list after sorting to check if it worked or not?

Comment: yup,i missed to display it

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
File file = new File("filepathname.txt");
file.delete();
file.creatFile();
```

Comment: i've tried it before, it didn't work. and your code is wrong, it should be file.createNewFile();

Answer (score 0):

File myFile = null;

BufferedReader br = null;

BufferedWriter bw = null;

String [] name = {

"John"," AnNa","1","AliCe",

"Ammy"," JOey","Alex","0"};


try {

myFile = new File("unsorted strings.txt");

myFile.createNewFile();

bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myFile));


for ( int i = 0; i < name.length; i++ ){

bw.write(name[i]);

bw.newLine();

}

bw.close();

br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));

String temp = "";

int counter = 0;

while((temp = br.readLine()) != null){

//temp = temp.trim();

//char fChar = temp.toUpperCase().charAt(0);

//temp = temp.substring(1,temp.length()).toLowerCase();

//name[counter] = fChar + temp;

//counter++;

name[counter] = temp;

counter++;

}


br.close();


//java.util.Arrays.sort(name);


java.util.Arrays.sort(name,new java.util.Comparator< String >(){
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

return o1.trim().toLowerCase().compareTo(o2.trim().toLowerCase());

}});



myFile = new File("sorted strings.txt");

myFile.createNewFile();

bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myFile));


for ( int i = 0; i < name.length; i++ ){

bw.write(name[i]);

bw.newLine();

}


bw.close();

myFile = new File("empty file.txt");

myFile.createNewFile();

bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myFile));

bw.write("");

bw.close();


}catch (Exception ex) {

ex.printStackTrace();

}